# Automated gzip compressing each file separately

Tags: caching, nginx, compression, gzip, on-the-fly

How can we compress each existing file separately with own original filename in specific directory & it's sub-directories.

This way I hope we don't need to run "on-the-fly gzip compress" every time for existing nginx fastcgi cache plain text files anymore.

That might be save lots of resources & also give us low latency/waiting time of serving already cached files.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to compress the files on your own - Nginx does not help you with that. For all files you want to pre-compress, just compress them and save them as "original filename + .gz at the end" (in the same directory), and then use the gzip_static option to serve these files.

So a working example of this could be:

```
http {
  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length  500;
  gzip_proxied     any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json image/svg+xml image/x-icon image/gif text/css application/x-javascript;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_disable     "msie6";
  gzip_static on; # this enables the .gz files being served

  ... here come your server blocks and other Nginx configuration
}
```

Now the .gz files are being served for all gzip_types, if they exist - for all websites. If you only want to use gzip_static in some directories / domains, you can remove it in the http block above and just add it in a location block - this is what I usually do.